# Install Numpy in Python 3.4.4 and Linux

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 which includes Python 2.7.11 and 3.5.1.

I also installed Python 3.4.4 successfully. But when I try to install `numpy` with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy 
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

it installs for Python 2.7.11 and 3.5.1 but I need it for Python 3.4.4. How do I install it?

Comment: Why don't you use pip?

Comment: pip install in python 2.7 and pip3 in 3.51... how can I install in 3.4.4?

Comment: Why `python 3.4.4` and not `python 3.5.1`? Any major difference?

Comment: Not for python, but for libraries to develop some optimization models. I work with operational research and, unfortunately, IBM CPLEX API is not compatible with python 3.5 yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/installing/index.html#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel): when working with multiple versions of Python installed in parallel, below commands can be used along with `pip` to install a Python Package for a particular version of Python:

```
python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
python3.5 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.5
```

Hence, to install `numpy` package for Python3.4, you can use this command:

```
~/$ python3.4 -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: Perfectly works! Thanks Orions! I upvoted, but will appear only when I have reputation more than 15

Comment: @plex you'll actually have to come back and upvote, [it doesn't automatically add your vote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326060/change-the-wording-of-thank-you-for-your-feedback-when-a-user-below-125-re)